# Merging similar columns in NumPy, probability vector

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I have a numpy array of the following shape:
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxJq1.png)

It is a probability vector, where the second row corresponds to a value and the first row to the probability that this value is realized. (e.g. the probability of getting 1.0 is 20%)

When two values are close to each other, I want to merge their columns by adding up the probabilities. In this example I want to have:
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNaiK.png)

My current solution involves 3 loops and is really slow for larger arrays. Does someone know an efficient way to program this in NumPy?

Comment: Please don't post images, it's not too hard to include two matrices. Also it's nice to post your code, because it's hard to speed up something without actually seeing it.

Comment: Sorry, I could not find an option to include a matrix or use latex.

Answer (score 0):

While it won't do exactly what you want, you could try to use [`np.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) to tackle the problem.

For example say you just want two "bins" like in your example you could do

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.01]])
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(x[1, :], bins=[0, 1.0, 1.5], weights=x[0, :])
```

and then stack your histogram with the leading bin edges to get your output

```
print(np.stack([hist, bin_edges[:-1]]))
```

This will print

```
[[0.7 0.3]
 [0.  1. ]]
```

You can use the `bins` parameter to get your desired output. I hope this helps.